# Reusing the inputstream of a socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

i would like to know how to keep the input stream of a socket and reuse it until the application is close.
What i do for now is creating a thread in the main method.  This thread is supposed to keep running for the all time the application runs.  In this thread i read data from the server using the socket input stream.  But i'm able to read only one time what the server is sending.  After that i think the thread is dead or i cannot read from the input stream.  How can i do to keep the input stream reading what is coming from the server.
Thanks.

```
int length = readInt(input);


    byte[] msg = new byte[length];
    input.read(msg);
ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bs);
            int cmd = readInt(in);
switch(cmd) {
case 1: Msg msg = readMsg(cmd, msg);
}
```

I put here everything, but in my code things happen in different methods.

The readInt method:

```
public static int readInt(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    int byte1 = in.read();
    int byte2 = in.read();
    int byte3 = in.read();
    int byte4 = in.read();
    if (byte4 == -1) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }
    return (byte4 << 24)
            + ((byte3 << 24) >>> 8)
            + ((byte2 << 24) >>> 16)
            + ((byte1 << 24) >>> 24);
}
```

Used for little-endian conversion.

Comment: Show us some code. It sounds like there's just nothing to read from the socket, so `read()` is blocking (waiting for there to be data to read).

Comment: I suggest sticking some print statements around to let you know what is going, or run it under a good debugger so you can see what is running and when it stops running.  Without code or actual knowledge of what the problem is, we are unlikely to be able to help you very much.

Comment: Also: what protocol are you using? Are you sure that *neither* the client *nor* the server are closing the socket (or its streams)?

Answer (score 1):

your socket might well be blocking. If you encounter such a problem one good way around is to design your software for a polling method rather than being interrupt driven. Then again, the software design pattern will be done around what you are trying to achieve.

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: I'm running the application in the netbeans profiler, and i see that my thread running the code for reading what the server is sending is finished...The thread finished as soon as i read something from the server.

Comment: Why did it finish?  Is it excepting out of your read() loop for some reason?

Comment: But i don't know why it finishes, it doesn't seem to be excepting out anything.  That is my run method : public void run() {
        try {
            handleReadServer(in);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Clazz.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }, if some exception were thrown i would see it, but i see nothing.

Comment: What's in your handlReadServer() routine? Maybe you could update your post and paste that section of your code there for us to checkout? Cheers!

Comment: Your code is blocking on the last read. Refer to: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read() . If you want, you might consider sending your own character delimiters as end of stream will return you -1 based on the specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call input.read() in a loop such as this:

```
try {
    while(running) {
        int length = readInt(input);
        byte[] msg = new byte[length];
        input.read(msg);
        ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bs);
            int cmd = readInt(in);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 1: Msg msg = readMsg(cmd, msg);
        }

     }
} catch (IOException e) { 
    //Handle error
}
```

Set running to false when you are finished with what ever your thread needs to be doing. Remember input.read() will block until the socket has received something. I hope this helps.